# How to create a task in background that runs every 5 minutes in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm working for a university project in witch I need to send statistics of a user every 5 minutes in background, no matter what he's doing in the app like switching between pages or closing the app (not killing) in Ionic.

I used the background mode plugin but the task is killed when I switch between pages because it starts when the user logs in.

tracking.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  BackgroundGeolocation,
  BackgroundGeolocationConfig,
  BackgroundGeolocationResponse,
  BackgroundGeolocationEvents
} from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation/ngx';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode/ngx';

@Injectable()
export class TrackingService {

  constructor(
    private backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocation,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode
  ) {
    this.backgroundMode.on('activate').subscribe(() => {
      console.log('activated background mode');
      this.backgroundMode.enable();
    });
  }

  trackingConfigurationGPS() {
    /* tracking configuration*/
  }

  startBackgroundGeolocation() {
    this.trackingGPS();
    var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
      this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
      this.backgroundGeolocation.stop();
    }, 30000);
  }

  sendGPS(location) {
    /* send data to api*/
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the task is being killed when you move around pages then you probably have the background code in the wrong place.

You should create it in an Angular `service` so that there is only one copy and it is shared between all the pages.

Please post the code you have so far if this doesn't resolve your issue.

## Update

Your timeout value for the interval is `30000`, are you waiting over 30 seconds after switching the page? Have you put some console.logs in there to try to see what is being called?

Comment: I tried to create it as a service, but it doesn't show anything when I switch pages

Comment: the code you have posted has `.stop()` straight after the `.start()` so its not going to do anything

Comment: I deleted that line but when I switch to another page it doesn't send anything

Comment: I put a few more ideas into my answer

Comment: I wait for 2 minutes and I put some console.logs to see if the data is sent and the response of the server. It works normally when I call the service but when I switch to another page the service stops and console shows nothing, on the server nothing else is received after the switch.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

App in foreground: Send data to api
App close: Show notification and send data to api first 5 minutes.
When app come foreground again: send every old data to api.

I think the problem is @angular/common/http
I try to use: cordova-plugin-advanced-http but work in same way.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.It's because of the interval and the HTTP requests. It's impossible to use them in background.

You should use: https://github.com/capacitor-community/http for http requests and the example in https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/apis/background-task for a date/time based interval.